# Enable 32 bits to a list of existing IIS appools

Tags: iis

Tried to find a list of appools in IIS starting with a common name "as" once found I would like to enable to only those 32bits to true

So far got this but it's not working, any given help will be very much appreaciated

```
import-module WebAdministration
$enable32bit="true"
$results = Get-IISAppPool | where {$_.Name -like "AS*"}
  foreach ($item in $results) {
  Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$item -Name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value $enable32bit
  }
```

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, I suggest modifying your script to call `Get-IISAppPool` without the where clause and print every item in the resultset to console. That way you can tell if the pool you want is even there.

Comment: Thanks John, did that printing the $results variable, then realized that the solution was much simpler Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\AS* -name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value "true"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly just this:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\AS* -name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value "true"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).